# How to XCreateWindow in the background?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm looking at improving developer experience when running graphics tests which spawn short-lived windows "like crazy". The windows need to be physically there, as otherwise data readback fails (i.e. **the window cannot be hidden**)

Needless to say, windows popping up at high frequency is unpleasant. I set out with the goal of finding a way to tell `XCreateWindow` to "create the window in the background", "not to steal focus" or something like that to no avail. The closest thing I could find is calling `XSetInputFocus` post-creation. Other than the fact that I couldn't make it work, I don't expect setting input focus to fully solve the issue anyway (as the windows would still pop up, just not without input focus, right?).

How is this done in X11?

---

P.S. The update notification on Ubuntu starts without popping to front, so this must be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've tried and admitedly failed doing what you want to do. Nevertheless I've found a few "close-enough"-solutions that may be of interest.

[XCreatePixmap](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/pixmap-and-cursor/XCreatePixmap.html) might work out, but in my case didn't have a pixmap with desired properties (multisampling) so it "out the window" (haha)

To prevent some level of spaming you might be able to set XCreateWindow `parent` to a an exisiting  window other than root, large enough to hold your tests and moved outside display. The parent window need be created, moved outside display and un-focused, but at least every window creation won't steal focus (I think) and spam on display.

Or you figure out a way to create additional displays, maybe using [Xvbf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). Didn't have admin access to corp dev env so didn't bother trying to install/configure, in addition to other obstacles, but it might just work for you.

Comment: It seems like such a simple feature to have, yet X does all sorts of arcane stuff instead :( Why does the parent window need to be "large"? If I understand correctly, what you are saying is that the test windows would end up being a "pop up" of the parent window? Also,when you say "un-focus", do you mean through `XSetInputFocus`?

Comment: @Shahbaz When creating a new window X (or maybe GNOME?) does `XSetInputFocus` to it - there is no stopping it. What you can do is finding the window in focus (`XQueryTree`) before creating the new window and invoke `XSetInputFocus` back to it once created. "Large" because otherwise the created window is clipped to parent borders. You might need a `XCompositeRedirectWindow` too, but I would try first before messing with it. I blame most my gray hairs on X. Get out before it happens to you.

Comment: Sadness. I think I'll go with `XQueryTree` + `XSetInputFocus` as a quick fix and don't get too deep in it. I'll accept your answer once I verify that it works.